# angular production build fails in Nx workspace due relative path

Tags: angular, build, production, nrwl-nx

When I trigger a production build for one of the angular (v11.x) libraries in our nx workspace (v11.x), I get the following error:

```
nx run i18n-components:build:production 
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point '@smallstack/i18n-components'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
√ Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
× Bundling to FESM2015
ERROR: Could not resolve '../../../../../../dist/libs/axios-api-client/src/index' from dist\libs\components\i18n-components\esm2015\lib\stores\locale.store.js
Could not resolve '../../../../../../dist/libs/axios-api-client/src/index' from dist\libs\components\i18n-components\esm2015\lib\stores\locale.store.js

———————————————————————————————————————————————

>  NX   ERROR  Running target "build" failed
```

Looking at the output in `locale.store.js` it seems that, instead of using the package name via tsconfig->paths, it tries to find the file via relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem... If you have a service that is `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })` or `@Injectable({ providedIn: "platform" })` which requires a service which isn't, you get that error.

I guess, root services shall only depend on other root services?